# Mvc3 check form values after Httppost

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, modelstate

I have 2 question, 1. I have an edit action and use a **formcollection** to get the value out of a HiddenFor on Httppost which then i use to make a change in another database table and I was wondering is there a way in which I can see the value of that FormCollection after form submit?

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(relisting house,FormCollection tt)
    {


        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {


// I would like a way to check the value of getid after submission since 
//my code isn't working. This is an EDIT Action so the GETID has a value 
 //atleast before the post.
            int getid = Convert.ToInt32(tt["RegistrationID"]);
var checksopen = (from d in db.openhouses where getid == d.RegistrationID 
select d).FirstOrDefault();

            house.squarefeet = checksopen.squarefeet;
            house.city = checksopen.city;

            db.Entry(checksopen).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();





        }
        return View(house);
    }
```

and my last question is that my full code above uses 2 db.Entry().State = EntityState.Modified; but only 1 is working; is there anything that can make the 2nd entity.modified not work? assuming that the **checksopen** does have a match? I am passing data from the parent model **relisting** to the child model **openhouse** , so for every openhouse there is a relisting so I want to capture the changes in both to keep it in sync.

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(relisting house,FormCollection tt)
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

 // This one works
            db.Entry(house).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();

// This one doesn't work

            int getid = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form["RegistrationID"]);

            var checksopen = (from d in db.openhouses where getid == 
    d.RegistrationID select d).FirstOrDefault();

            house.squarefeet = checksopen.squarefeet;
            house.city = checksopen.city;

            db.Entry(checksopen).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();





        }
        return View(house);
    }
```

Comment: for related issue of `db.SaveChanges()` look at - http://stackoverflow.com/a/12050697/143796

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I was wondering is there a way in which I can see the value of that FormCollection after form submit?

It is possible. Your code may pass the parameter into a property of the `Model` that you return back after post action. `return View(house);` You are returning model named `house`. Just add a new public parameter to this model and assign your `RegistrationID` to it.

**Tip:** for performance considerations, there is no need to post the `FormCollection`, as it posts every item that you have in your view. Posting only the `Model` that contains necessary properties with hidden model values would be a better approach.